# Высокопроизводительная обработка данных

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, архитектура, производительность

Помогите советом. Создаю приложение на Spring Boot, которое будет оперировать большим количеством данных, при этом важна оперативность этой обработки.

Для примера:

50 таблиц, в каждой цены на какие-то товары/услуги. Записей в таблице от 5000. Каждая таблица отдельный поставщик товаров и услуг. Цены на товары и услуги обновляются раз 5-10 минут, т.е. все 5000 записей обновляются. Необходимо оперативно сравнивать цены товаров/услуг между поставщиками. Выборка будет соответственно по каждым товарам/услугам, в том числе Join-ы, т.к. у некоторые товары могут иметь состовляющие, которые имеют свои цены. Дальше значения по выбранному товару/услуге будут сравниваться между всеми поставщиками.

Логичное решение для увеличения производительности, я вижу в использовании Memory таблиц.
Собственно, хотелось бы услышать совет от опытных в этом деле.
Какими средствами это реализовать?
Стоит ли использовать ORM и Hibernate, или они только утяжелят все транзакции?
Подойдет ли Embeded база Sprin Boot-а или лучше использовать стороннюю?

Comment: А вам вообще нужна реляционная БД для этого?

Comment: Как бы с таким количеством записей сложно даже искусственный хайлоуд сделать. Если нужна скорость и все выглядит надежным можно отказаться от использования транзакций, это ускорит сильно. Memory таблицы тут вообще не дались, только зря время будет потрачено.

Comment: @Nofate Для долговременного хранения нужна только таблица соответствия товаров/услуг, чтобы было проще их сопоставлять. Все остальное хранить не нужно. Товары/услуги будут браться от поставщика

Comment: Мне кажется, что это все в большей степени вопросы к базе данных -- какую взять, как настроить. Я б взял PostgreSQL. Не удивлюсь, если даже на средней машинке у вас не будет проблем, главное индексы не забудьте поставить :) Hibernate я бы брать не стал в любом случае.

Comment: @DEADMC почему Memory таблицы не подойдут? Я считал, что выборка данных из оперативной памяти даст прирост производительности, в сравнении с выборкой из БД, или это незначительные цифры?

Comment: @Алексей в твоих масштабах даже разницы не заметишь. Честно говоря у меня около 10 запросов каждые 6 секунд, причем там и на выборку и на апдейт, с вложенными и джоинами (в одном около 7 джоинов) в разные таблицы, некоторые из которых содержат около 10000 записей, которые опять же и выбираются и обновляются и все работает моментально практически. Основная идея в том, чтобы, как тут заметили, правильно расставить индексы и оптимизировать по максимуму сами запросы.

Comment: @Алексей еще что весьма может помочь это вынести все инертные данные в само приложение и выгружать, например, при первом запуске.

Comment: @Алексей а вообще лучше сначала сделать чтоб тупо работало, а потом уже изголяться по поводу ускорения по мере необходимости. Как когда-то верно заметил Дональд Кнут - "преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол".

Comment: @DEADMC Если смотреть на перспективу, что товаров/услуг и поставщиков будет становиться все больше, а данные не нужны для долгого хранения (только на момент обработки). Как можно было бы увеличить производительность в этом случае?

Comment: Возможно (как вариант, я сам не проверял, это только предположение), в случае, если данные нужно просто временно хранить для обработки (сравнения) и со временем удалять, в качестве хранилища использовать какое-то NoSQL решение, заточенное на скорость (например, Aerospike), которое умеет отдавать данные быстро, а также имеет функцию очистки устаревших данных. Но, ИМХО, как тут уже правильно заметили, это не те объемы, на которых заметите разницу.

Comment: С каких это пор обновление 5 тыс. записей раз в 5-10 минут является тяжелой задачей - я весь в недоумении...

Comment: 5000 это очень мало. Для задач подобного рода я бы вообще взял sqlite или любую файловую бд. А вообще советую PostgresSQL -> jsonb, и храните там хоть слона хоть коня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, под вашу небольшую нагрузку (обновление 5000 записей раз в 5-10 минут) сгодится практически любая БД.

Рекомендую не изощряться с Memory (если не знаете как пользоваться скорее потеряете данные, чем получите производительность), ORM и Hibernate, и тем более пока не переходить на PostgreSQL или NoSQL (это решения для очень больших объемов данных, целесообразно начинать их использовать при таблицах от 100-200 млн. записей и более). Для вашей задачи используйте классический MySQL.

Во-вторых, что касается производительности, сделайте следующее:

- обязательно проставьте индексы в соответствии с вашим профилем нагрузки
- выполняйте UPDATE не единичными запросами, а пачками под максимальную длину используемого у вас SQL-запроса (на практике это намного ускоряет производительность).
- выполните запросы в транзакциях.
- в качестве ключей для поиска строк при обновлении данных старайтесь использовать только INT значения (а еще лучше, если этот столбец будет и PRIMARY KEY).

P.S. На будущее рекомендую отходить от JOIN'ов в сторону денормализации данных. Запросы с объединением нескольких таблицы плохо масштабируются, когда сама база уже не влезает на один сервер.

Answer (score -2):

Если стоит условие отказаться от базы данных и ускорить работу приложения, то используйте только файлы - вытащили данные , например с xml, сравнили , изменили и опять закинули туда же, чтобы освободить память. Но приросте данных у вас будет константа обработки их- тоесть все будет работать достаточно быстро, но оперативную память будет кушать не мало....